# Is it possible to connect two private eBGP peers with the same AS number?

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp

**The Problem**

A third party has implemented a small network and private BGP setup within one of our branches. We need to setup a eBGP peer relationship with this network. However we are both using the same private BGP AS number.

**The Solution**

1. *One of us changes our BGP AS number* - This isn't out of the question, and even if there is another solution but its overly complex we may still do this.
2. *BGP Confederation* - In my research it appears that setting up a BGP Confederation between the peers might be a work around. The basic idea would be to sub-divide the shared private AS number into multiple private AS numbers. I'm not entirely sure yet whether this would solve the problem properly.
3. *Other solutions*? It is here I'm looking for more advice on whether it is possible to work around this problem is an effective way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

Option 1 is likely your best bet for simplicity's sake, but you *can* use the confederation method if you don't want to change the ASN. You can also do `neighbor x.x.x.x local-as <as>` in the BGP config but this prepends an ASN of your choosing onto the path, rather than replace the ASN in the path, so updates from one router to the other would be dropped anyway. Unless there's a *really* good reason as to why you want to maintain the eBGP session, you can also migrate to an iBGP session vs eBGP.

As @DanielDib has pointed out below, a third option (if you're running a version of IOS that supports it) is to use `local-as` in conjunction with `replace-as` and `no-prepend` to strip your ASN from the AS_PATH and send a different one:

```
router bgp [your asn]
  neighbor x.x.x.x remote-as [peer-asn]
  neighbor x.x.x.x local-as [new asn] no-prepend replace-as
```

Comment: I suppose they don't *have* to be eBGP peers. Though wouldn't it be standard practice to keep peers you don't manage as eBGP peers?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it may be useful if you provided a little more information (or desired requirements) regarding this third party and why a BGP session is necessary, and what you expect to be exchanging with the third party.

Comment: If one wants to make it look entirely as another AS, the local-as command with replace-as can be used and also optionally no-prepend.

Comment: Nice - I wasn't aware of that functionality. Updating my answer.

Comment: Damn, that's a nice solution. Thanks guys!

Comment: 'neighbor x.x.x.x local-as no-prepend replace-as' is probably your best bet. I believe you would also need to do a 'neighbor x.x.x.x allowas-in' for that peer so that your router doesn't filter out all incoming NLRI's which already contain your local ASN. That is the BGP loop prevention mechanism. You would also want to then apply an inbound prefix-list/route-map to that neighbor in order to prevent your own IP space from being sent back to you as you are effectively disabling the loop prevention. You could also iBGP peer and do a 'neighbor x.x.x.x next-hop-self', but I would go w/ local-as